# select min and max values before a particular row per customerID SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1, netezza, gaps-and-islands

I have a table which has info about visitors to our website.

So it will look like

`VISITOR_ID EVENT Date Rank` ( I already ranked them portioned by event)

```
Visitor_id  Event       Date    rank
1           visit       1/1/14  1
1           purchase    1/2/14  2
1           visit       1/3/14  3
1           visit       1/4/14  4
1           purchase    1/5/14  5
1           visit       1/6/14  6
1           visit       1/7/14  7
1           visit       1/8/14  8
1           purchase    1/9/14  9
```

I want to find all the min and max visit dates ( so the first and last visit before every purchase every user made)
 before every purchase so the result should have dates

```
visitor   mindate       maxdate 
1         1/1/2014      1/1/2014 (in this scenario there was only one visit before a purchase)
1         1/3/2014      1/4/2014 ( 2 OR MORE VISITS BEFORE A PURCHASE)
1         1/6/2014      1/8/2014
```

This is just an example for one visitor. The table has around a million visitors. Please help.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "min" and "max" date? It looks like you have only one date stored for each row in the table.

Comment: I can see that you're new to Stack Overflow, welcome!  After reading your question a few times, I'm still unsure of what exactly you want to do.  Since you're new, you should check out [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Also, give a couple examples of what you've already tried and what has failed.  As great as a resource SO is, you have to earn good answers by asking good questions.  Try editing and delineating your problem.

Comment: Note this falls into the larger category of `gaps-and-islands`, of which there are many examples on this site.

Comment: hello, The min date is the first visit of the user before a purchase and max date is the last visit date before the purchase...

Comment: let me read about gaps and islands.. Thanks Cloclwork…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break the visits into groups.  You can do this with a simple trick.  If you enumerate the rows for visits and subtract from the rank, then each group will have a constant value.  So, this is easy:

```
select visitor, min(date) as mindate, max(date) as maxdate
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by visitor order by rank) as v_rank
      from table t
      where event = 'Visit'
     ) t
group by visitor, (rank - v_rank);
```

Comment: Hello Gordon, Thanks for the answer… but it doesn't work… The current snippet just gives me every date in the table as max and min

Comment: @user3571236 . . . If this code doesn't work, then I suspect that your actual data is different from the data in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative:

```
SELECT
    visitor_id
    , MIN(Date)
    , MAX(Date)
FROM
visitors v
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
    rank
FROM visitors
WHERE Event = 'purchase' AND v.visitor_id = visitors.visitor_id) purchases
WHERE v.rank < purchases.rank
GROUP BY v.visitor_id, v.rank;
```

Comment: This gives me the same result as last one…. from the example: it gives me one row for each time rank visitor_id min max 1 1/1/2014 1/1/2014 1 1/2/2014 1/2/2014 1 1/3/2014 1/3/2014 …… i would like to get the min and max dates before every purchase made by every visitor so it would be visitor_id min max 1 1/1/2014 1/1/2014 1 1/3/2014 1/4/2015 1 1/6/2014 1/8/2014 I appreciate your attempt to help me… :)